# Error while downloading the zip file from server to device?

Tags: java, android, zip

I am using this code to download zip file from server

```
private static InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) 
        throws IOException
        {
            InputStream in = null;
            int response = -1;

            URL url = new URL(urlString); 
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                     
                throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

            try{
                System.out.println("OpenHttpConnection called");

                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
                httpConn.setDoInput(true);
                httpConn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "binary/data");

                httpConn.connect(); 

                response = httpConn.getResponseCode();

                System.out.println("response is"+response);
                System.out.println(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);

                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    in = httpConn.getInputStream();
                    System.out.println("Connection Ok");
                    return in;
                    }                     
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new IOException("Error connecting");            
            }
            return in;     
        }
```

and

```
                 private static void saveToInternalSorage(InputStream in,String filename,Context ctx){



//fos =openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

try {
  //  System.out.println("mypath = "+mypath);
    //fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
    FileOutputStream fos = (ctx).openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];






    int len1 ;
    while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer) )!=-1 ) {
        fos.write(buffer);


    }

    // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream


} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

The zip file which is downloaded is corrupted , the actual size of the file is 3.5kb but the downloaded file is of 5kb .What is the problem with the code please help?

Comment: `            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new IOException("Error connecting");            
            }`... this code will confuse you if some other exception is thrown in the try block.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer) )!=-1 ) {
        fos.write(buffer);


    }
```

You are writing the entire buffer in each iteration (1024 bytes). You should only write `len1` bytes (number of bytes read).

On a side-note, you may want to look at using some higher level abstraction libraries for stuff like HTTP and stream manipulation. Apache [Commons HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) and [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) for instance.

Comment: thanx it worked...but still when i try to unzip it ..winzip shows corrupt file

Comment: Is there anyway to check and change to normal form?

Answer (score 0):

```
            httpConn.setDoOutput(false);
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length());

while (... > 0) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);


fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Write only the bytes which are filled in the buffer i.e only len1 bytes. It will solve your problem as if the buffer is not filled completely, we will write only those bytes which are read.

```
    while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer) )!=-1 ) {
        fos.write(subArray(buffer,len1));    
    }

//Method to create su-array
    public byte[] subArray(byte[] arr, int length) {
        byte temp[] = new byte[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            temp[i] = arr[i];
        }
        return temp;
    }
```